# Enable Disable options in Select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select fields. for min points and max points. Range is 5000 to 50000, What I want to achive is in maxpoint select box I want to display the values which are greater than min points selected value.

for example if I select 15000 from minpoint select field, then in my maxpoint select box I want to hide/disable first two options (5000 and 10000) because they are less than 15000.

Baiscally enabling and disabling the maxpoints based on minpoints.

HTML looks like this

```
<select class="pointSelect" tabindex="2" id="minPoints" name="minPoints">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Min</option>
<option value="5000">5000</option>
<option value="10000">10000</option>
<option value="15000">15000</option>
<option value="20000">20000</option>
<option value="25000">25000</option>
<option value="30000">30000</option>
<option value="40000">40000</option>
<option value="50000">50000</option>
</select>
<select class="pointSelect" tabindex="3" id="maxPoints" name="maxPoints">
<option value="50000" selected="selected">Max</option>
<option value="5000">5000</option>
<option value="10000">10000</option>
<option value="15000">15000</option>
<option value="20000">20000</option>
<option value="25000">25000</option>
<option value="30000">30000</option>
<option value="40000">40000</option>
<option value="50000">50000</option>
</select>
```

I am trying something like this but not up to the mark yet

```
    $('#minPoints').change(function(){
    var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
    $('maxPoints').find('option').lt(index).attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('maxPoints').find('option').gt(index).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

Can someone please guide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show and hide the options selectively based on their index:

```
$('#minPoints').change(function () {
    var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
    $('#maxPoints').find('option:lt(' + index + ')').hide();
    $('#maxPoints').find('option:gt(' + index + ')').show();
});

$('#maxPoints').change(function () {
    var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
    $('#minPoints').find('option:gt(' + index + ')').hide();
    $('#minPoints').find('option:lt(' + index + ')').show();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbUwH/1/)

Comment: Thanks friend!  I think this is something called thinking out of the box and providing the innovative solution! It helps a lot thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You rather use `lt` or `gt` this way -

```
$("#maxPoints").find("option:lt("+index+")").attr("disabled","disabled");
$("#maxPoints").find("option:gt("+index+")").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Working fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7nmrk/2/)

Comment: This is good, although I would probably recommend using `.prop("disabled", true)` and `.prop("disabled", false)` instead ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kq9nY/)).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me @MotaBOS, I assumed the example in the question was working on in some aspects. Have removed my answer.

Comment: @RubenInfante - Yes I agree.